# How to change default app icon shape in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I started using Android Studio recently and I found one thing different (notably) that unlike in Eclipse, Android Studio does not provide any option to choose *app icon* and its *shape & size* while creating a new app. 
While finalizing my app development I tried to change default 'ic_launcher.png' with my own image but I am not able to change its shape (which is *square* by default) to *circular*.

So my question is - Is there any way of changing app icon shape in Android Studio ?
And if this question is already been solved on some other thread then please share that link with me. (P.S.- I tried to search with similar question here but couldn't find probable solution, therefore posting this question on my own)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add new Icons in all drawable folder and update the icon name in manifest file.

To change the icon shape following tool can be usefull:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: I have changed the default app icon but how to change it's shape??
are you suggesting to create a circular icon instead??

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer first of all. Here is my answer:

While launching [***Android Studio 1 RC in Beta Channel***](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiorc1inbetachannel), they did not add this feature of adding *image assets* to the app directly from the Android Studio.
But since ***[Android Studio 1.1](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio11released)*** update, this feature is available to use.
Here is how you get different icons:

1. Click on ***res*** under ***app*** directory of you project.
2. *New* --> *Image Asset*
3. Choose *Asset Type* (Launcher Icon | Action Bar and Tab Icons | Notification Icon).
4. Choose your Image from the directory and perform other necessary changes to get the icon you desire.
5. Click *next* and then select
   *Type Module* and *Res Directory* and click Finish.

You will see your icons under ***res*** folder directory.

I hope this was helpful, thank you!